# Powershell Scripting Issues (Newbie)

Tags: powershell

Ok, am having some issues with my script, they probably are pretty apparent but here is the script. Would greatly appreciate a review of the script with some feedback as why they are broken.

```
## Script Startup
$Computers = Get-Content .\computers.txt
$Total = $Computers.length
$consoleObject = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI

## Set Variables
$Run = 0
$Successful = 0

# Checks to see if there is a log file already created. If so check number of successful computer ran against, if not, create the log file.
IF ( test-path .\~temp.txt ) {
    $Log = Get-Content .\~temp.txt
    ForEach ($LogLine in $Log) {
    $LogCheck = $LogLine.ToString().Split(",")[2]
        IF ( "$LogCheck" -eq "Successful" ) {
            $Successful += 1
        }
    }
} ELSE {
    add-content .\~temp.txt "Computer Name,Attempts,Last Attempt,Time,Date"
}



while ( "$Completed" -le "$total" ) {
    $Run += 1
    $Time = Get-Date
    $consoleObject.WindowTitle = “Admin Check - $Successful Out Of $Total Successful `| Run`: $Run”

    ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {
        IF ( Select-String .\~temp.txt -pattern "$Computer" -quiet ) {
            $LogUpdate = Select-String .\~Temp.txt -pattern $Computer
            $Attempts = $LogUpdate.ToString().Split(",")[1]
            $Result = $LogUpdate.ToString().Split(",")[3]
        } ELSE {
            add-content .\~temp.txt "$Computer,0,Not Checked,Not Run Yet,Not Run Yet"
            $Attempts = ""
            $Result = ""
        }

        IF ( "$Result" -eq "Successful") {
            write-output "$Computer Already Completed"
        } ELSE {
            IF ( test-connection $Computer -quiet ) {
                # Command Here
                $Successful += 1
                $IsOn = "True"
            } ELSE {
                $IsOn = "False"
            }
            $Attempts += 1
        }
        ( Get-Content .\~temp.txt ) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "$Computer,.*", ($Computer + "," + $Attempts + "," + $IsOn + "," + $Result + "," + $Time.ToShortTimeString() + "," + $Time.ToShortDateString())} | Set-Content .\~temp.txt
    }
}
```

~temp.txt

```
Computer Name,Attempts,Last Attempt Result,Time,Date
52qkkgw-94210jv,11111111111111,False,,8:47 PM,10/27/2012
HELLBOMBS-PC,11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,True,,8:47 PM,10/27/2012
52qkkgw-94210dv,11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,False,,8:46 PM,10/27/2012
```

Current Issue:
 - Doesn't actually stop when successful equals total.
 - doesn't check result vs successful so keeps redoing all comps forever.
 - The Attempts tab just keeps adding 1 to the last time or something, so it makes some weird continuous "1111" thing.
Probably more just havn't noticed them yet.

Comment: Where is $Completed defined? I see $Run getting incremented but don't see $Completed anywhere. Also, remove those quotes off of your numeric variables. And set them like this [int32]$Run=0 so that they are cast properly as integers.

Comment: And I forgot : You have a $Total variable and a $total variable. Fix the casing on that as well since variables are case-sensitive.

Comment: variables are most definitely ***not*** case sensitive in Powershell.

Comment: Aren't they? My mistake then. That is just a holdover from all my other languages. Never make assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's working code:

```
clear
## Script Startup
$Computers = Get-Content \computers.txt
cd c:\pst
$Total = $Computers.length
$consoleObject = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI

## Set Variables
$Run = 1
$Successful = 0

# Checks to see if there is a log file already created. If so check number of successful         computer ran against, if not, create the log file.
IF ( test-path .\~temp.txt ) {
$Log = Get-Content .\~temp.txt
ForEach ($LogLine in $Log) {
$LogCheck = $LogLine.ToString().Split(",")[2]
    IF ( "$LogCheck" -eq "Successful" ) {
        $Successful += 1
    }
}
} ELSE {
add-content .\~temp.txt "Computer Name,Attempts,Last Attempt,Time,Date"
}

while ( $Run -ne $total ) {
$Run += 1
$Time = Get-Date
$consoleObject.WindowTitle = “Admin Check - $Successful Out Of $Total Successful `| Run`: $Run”

ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    IF ( Select-String .\~temp.txt -pattern "$Computer" -quiet ) {
        $LogUpdate = Select-String .\~Temp.txt -pattern $Computer
        $Attempts = $LogUpdate.ToString().Split(",")[1]
        $Result = $LogUpdate.ToString().Split(",")[3]
    } ELSE {
        add-content .\~temp.txt "$Computer,0,Not Checked,Not Run Yet,Not Run Yet"
        $Attempts = ""
        $Result = ""
    }

    IF ( "$Result" -eq "Successful") {
        write-output "$Computer Already Completed"
    } ELSE {
        IF ( test-connection $Computer -quiet ) {
            # Command Here
            $Successful += 1
            $IsOn = "True"
        } ELSE {
            $IsOn = "False"
        }
        $Attempts += 1
    }
    ( Get-Content .\~temp.txt ) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "$Computer,.*", ($Computer + "," + $Attempts + "," + $IsOn + "," + $Result + "," + $Time.ToShortTimeString() + "," + $Time.ToShortDateString())} | Set-Content .\~temp.txt
}
}
```